# Converting data in NAD83 (NSRS 2007) to NAD83 (CORS 96)

Tags: coordinate-system

I have some control points from NGS that are in NAD83 (NSRS 2007) that I would like to merge with the rest of our control point dataset, but our existing data are in NAD83(CORS 96), I think, or it could be NAD83 (2001).

Which NAD83 is inherent in ESRI's NAD_1983_StatePlane_Georgia_West_FIPS_1002_Feet coordinate system (Geographic: GCS_North_American_1983  Datum:   D_North_American_1983)?

In any case, does anyone know of any transformations for converting NAD83 (NSRS 2007) to one of the "regular" NAD83 datums?

NGS will not be publishing any, and ESRI does not have a transformation filter for it.

I read the GIS SE posts from last year regarding NAD83<-->HARN conversions, but I am wondering if anyone has dealt successfully with this issue since then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esri added HARN/NSRS2007, NSRS2007/WGS84 and CORS96/NSRS2007 transformations to ArcGIS 10.0, but they're all 'bookkeeping'--parameters are zeroes. I think you would have to get a geodetic surveyor to calculate a transformation by running a least squares fit using control points in both systems. I know of two cities on the west coast that have done so.

Answer (score 3):

NSRS 2007 and CORS 96 are functionally equivalent.  The NAD(CORS96) realization only includes the CORS stations. The passive marks were subsequently re-adjusted based on GPS observations from the CORS using CORS96 positions. This re-adjustment of the passive marks is referred to as NSRS2007.

The current realization is NAD(2011). In many places the difference between NSRS2007 and NAD(2011) is less than 0.025m. If your control points have a network accuracy error less than 0.025m you might want to try to adjust your data to NAD(2011). But if your control point error is greater than the 2007-2011 shift in your area, there is no point trying to adjust your data.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to the first question.
The vertical datum is managed seperately from the horizontal in Esri.
When configuring a new feature class check the "will contain Z values" and then there is another tab next to coordinate system "z coordinate system".

[image: Picture1]

And on existing feature classes with z enabled.
The dialog looks similar.

[image: Picture2]

The second question...
I can think of a way to accomplish it. As to the accuracy I cannot speak.
1. Create a personal or file geodatabase,
2. Create a feature data set and
3. define the target crs and vertical system,
4. create an empty feature class
5. using the original data to define the schema of the target feature class.
6. Use the load cammand to load the original data into the target feature class.